# jQuery chosen dropdown search functionality without the search box

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Is there a way to leave the search box disabled but still have the dropdown select an option on keypress which is the default behavior while the search is enabled?

```
$(element).chosen({ disable_search: true });
```

I have tried enabling the search and hiding the search box (with no luck) using:

```
$('ul.chosen-choices li.search-field').hide();
```

it seems as if that search needs to be displayed for the keypress to work like a normal select. Has anyone had any luck? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an [issue](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/2593) in the Chosen github issue queue about this very problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works for me, however it needs some adjustments for special character handling:

```
var originalObjectSelector = "select#yourSelectId";

var $container = $(originalObjectSelector).data("chosen").container

var $orig=$(originalObjectSelector);

$container.bind("keypress", function(event){
    var charCode = event.charCode; 
    var keyCode = event.keyCode; 
    var character = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    //console.log("kc:", keyCode, "cc", charCode, "char:", character);
    //console.log(event);
    if(keyCode==13){
        //enter is pressed;
        $orig.trigger('change');
    }
    if(charCode != 0 && character.match(/^[-_ a-zA-Z0-9]+$/))
    {
        //console.log('alphanumeric or space');      
        $orig.find("option").removeAttr("selected")
            .filter(function() { return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(character.toLowerCase()) === 0; })
            .first().attr("selected", "selected");
        $orig.trigger('chosen:updated');
    } 

});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. For people who are searching for the same thing, I am using this inside of a knockout binding handler. It is being done in the INIT function of the handler. This is obviously done after the $(element).chosen(); is called. Thank you!